# Clear the input with required value

Tags: ruby, capybara

I have some issue with clearing css input field. Input field has a prefilled "required value" and I can't clear. https://take.ms/UoMB9

I already tried

```
find('input[name=email]').set('')
el = find('input[name=email]')
el.native.clear
```

this code clearing only value, but not "required value"

Would be appreciated if someone can help this

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confused by what you're looking at.  There is no "required value" attribute, the element has a `value` attribute equal to "1561540348@@test.co" and also has a `required` attribute which specifies to HTML5 form validation not to submit the form if the field is empty - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation#The_required_attribute

Clearing the field with something like

```
fill_in('email', with: '')
```

will set the elements `value` property (not the same as the attribute, but the property is what actually gets submitted) to empty however the browser won't let you submit the form due to validation failing. If this doesn't explain/answer your issue please explain more fully what exactly you're trying to do.